# Opening 32-bit process crash dumps in 64-bit Windows (so Wow process) in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, dump

CpupSyscallStub is what I See for all threads, in Windbg I can switch to 32-bit mode and get the real threads.

How do I do this in VS2010?

Comment: OR more easily said, how do I see 32-bit threads in a Wow process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you take this process dump? via Task Manager (taskmgr)?

If so, it is a 64-bit dump of a 32-bit process and these cannot be debugged with Visual Studio 2010, and there is no way to switch the architecture.

Try retaking the dump using Visual Studio or WinDbg or ADPlus.

You can read more about types of dumps, etc. @ MiniDumpWriteDump  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that a 32-bit dump can also be created with the 32-bit task manager ("%systemroot%\syswow64\taskmgr.exe"). Close the existing 64-bit taskmgr first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ProcDump.  It captures 32-bit processes as 32-bit dumps by default.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/09/29/capturing-memory-dumps-for-32-bit-processes-on-an-x64-machine.aspx